# Why is "complete action using" popping up for this intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

I just linked some social networks to my app as a preliminary test and using the same kind of code, the results I am getting are different for Facebook, Instagram and Twitter intents.

When I click Facebook or Twitter, it opens the app automatically when it's installed and uses browser when it's not. However, that's not the case with Instagram. The complete action using dialog pops up and that's not something I want to happen.

```
protected void LaunchInstagram() {
    String InstagramUsername = "USERNAME";
    String LaunchInstagram = "http://instagram.com/_u/" + InstagramUsername;
    String InstagramURL = "https://instagram.com/" + InstagramUsername;
    try {
        this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.instagram.android", 0);
        Uri Uri = Uri.parse(LaunchInstagram);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri));
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException InstagramAppNotFoundOpenBrowser) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(InstagramURL)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

String InstagramURL = "https://instagram.com/" + InstagramUsername;

So every Intent you'll try to launch, will open a chooser because this is a URL.

than every App that supports URL, like browsers and such, will try to handle that.

EDIT 1:

Try it this way:

```
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
            //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that will help you to open a specific user page on the App thou.

EDIT 2:

Try it this way:

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/USERNAME");
    Intent insta = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    insta.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(insta);
```

Comment: I understand now, is there a way to edit LaunchInstagram string so the try block will redirect to Instagram app if installed directly?